# Cant connect jenkins to bitbucket repository

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have installed Jenkins on a ubuntu server.I tried to integrate a bitbucket repository with Jenkins.but it gives an error appeared in the screenshot.I added the Jenkins server public key to bitbucket access key and also I have read write permission in bitbucket.Can some point out a solution?

[image]

Comment: Is `SSH` between Jenkins server and `Bitbucket` working?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67315551/9956279

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the SSH host key in your `known_host` file on the jenkins server:

```
 jenkins@jenkins_host $ ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You can also just try to ssh into bitbucket.com from the jenkins server and then accept the ssh host key.